# Can't connect to WiFi after resuming from long hibernation (NetworkManager, wpa_supplicant)

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager

After resuming from hibernation, my laptop (Framework 13 AMD) gets disconnected from Wifi and I am unable to connect until I reboot.
Relevant logs (from `journalctl`, timestamp corresponds resuming time):

```
Feb 21 16:06:13 framy NetworkManager[1307]: <warn>  [1708527973.6007] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Feb 21 16:06:13 framy NetworkManager[1307]: <warn>  [1708527973.6806] device (wlp1s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Livebox-F060'
```

`ip a` (only relevant):

```
3: wlp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a6:72:f3:30:7c:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr a8:3b:76:72:eb:e5
```

`nmcli` (only relevant):

```
wlp1s0: disconnected
    "MEDIATEK MT7922 802.11ax"
    wifi (mt7921e), 7E:66:4D:F2:69:AE, hw, mtu 1500

p2p-dev-wlp1s0: disconnected
    "p2p-dev-wlp1s0"
    wifi-p2p, hw
```

Additional system info:

- Distribution: NixOS
- Kernel version: 6.7.5

Edit: Running `sudo modprobe -r mt7921e` and `sudo modprobe mt7921e` to reload the kernel module brings back wifi capability.